# Server Error when using Formik components and Axios onSubmiting function Next.js

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, axios, formik

I'm having this problem, when I use Axios in `onSubmit(() => { ... code here ... })` I instantly receive this error:

```
Server Error
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
```

This is my component structure:

```js
import { Formik, Form } from "formik"
import FormField from "./FormField"
import SubmitButton from "./SubmitButton"
import { signInSchema } from "./handlers/formHandlers"
import axios from "axios"

export interface FormValues {
    email: string,
    password: string,
}

const FormComponent = () => {
    const initialValues: FormValues = { email: '', password: '' }
    return (
        <div className="flex flex-col">
            <h1 className="font-Inter-Bold text-green-500 uppercase text-2xl">Register</h1>
            <Formik
                initialValues={initialValues}
                validationSchema={signInSchema}
                onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
                    actions.setSubmitting(false)
                    axios.post("http://localhost:8000/api/auth/register", {email: values.email, password: values.password}, {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}})
                }}
            >
                <Form className="font-Inter-Bold text-xl sm:text-2xl">
                    <FormField 
                        FIELD_LABEL="EMAIL"
                        FIELD_NAME="email"
                        FIELD_TYPE="text"
                        FIELD_ID="email"
                        FIELD_PLACEHOLDER="example@here.com"
                    />
                    <FormField 
                        FIELD_LABEL="PASSWORD"
                        FIELD_NAME="password"
                        FIELD_TYPE="password"
                        FIELD_ID="password"
                        FIELD_PLACEHOLDER="*******"
                    />
                    <SubmitButton />
                </Form>
            </Formik>
        </div>
    )
}

export default FormComponent
```

I have to mention that I'm using Next.js **14.0.1** and I tried using fetch function, but I have the same exact error